# Defining a function which uses an array as input

Tags: c

How to define a function in C like `int MatrixPrint(int a[3][3])` with integer variables in place of `3`?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to define a function which is like int array[int a][int b] when defined like int array[3][3] it works. I want to replace 3s with two integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int MatrixPrint(int a[int a][int b])
```

This is not correct. Instead do the following way:

```
int MatrixPrint(int rows, int columns, int a[rows][columns])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `int MatrixPrint(int a[3][3])` is correct and works
2. `int MatrixPrint(int a[int a][int b])` is not correct and does not work.

you don't have to mention the type of size of the array, but you can pass them either as you mentioned in case 1. or with any valid identifier names.

when you pass an array to function it is actually treated as a pointer , so you can actually use

`void fun(int (*mat)[3]);` in place of `int MatrixPrint(int a[3][3])` or `int MatrixPrint(int a[r][c])`.